# How to Move/Migrate the Teams channel post from one channel to another

Tags: post, office365, chat, microsoft-teams, migrate

Is there any way to transfer the Microsoft teams all posts from one channel to another channel on the same account apart from copy/paste?

Comment: It is not possible with today's capabilities. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Microsoft Teams feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Answer (score 0):

No, Microsoft Teams does not allow to do so. You only have option of copy and paste. You can also cross-post the message from one chat to another channel. If you want to know more about it:-
[Move MS Teams Coversations](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/move-msteams-conversation-into-channel/283628ac-f535-4622-b203-8ad9373ddec6)
OR
[Move channels Between Teams](https://migratorwizard.com/teams/transfer-channels-to-another/)